# Graphic cards, what could be their bottle-necks?

Tags: 3d, animation

A friend of mine is willing to buy or assemble a computer mainly for graphic design of course but more specifically for `3D animation` (short movies) and running heavy programs such as: Maya, 3D-Max, after-effect and some others.

After a bit of searching for a good GC (Graphic Card) that has the capability to handle and process such hard and complicated tasks (animating, rendering, adding effects and so) we got to know that Nvidia is already offering a great series of GC specialized in CAD & 3D that is called `Quadro` ... but unfortunately it is unbelievably un-affordable at all !
So we decided to look after Nvidia GTX series or some others.

The question is: if we bought the last GTX one for example, what could be its limitations/capabilities in animation designing if we know that Nvidia says that GTX is not designed for CAD & 3D ? what is its bottle-neck mainly ? to what point we couldn't reach beyond and this GC breaks down ?

Is it better to buy some old Quadro models rather than buying new GTX ? and what about other brands, I mean ATI for example ?

P.S: our budget is barely ~700-800$

Comment: If your friend doesn't know if he needs Quadro, he doesn't need Quadro. :)

Comment: yeah I agree, then is GTX capable to process heavy animations smoothly ?

Comment: All is relative.. I'm sure there are a thousand pages online describing the differences if you google around. My impression is that nearly every animator have started on a typical consumer ATI or Nvidia card. Then maybe years later when becoming part of a pro team you move on to more serious HW. Also I seem to recall Quadro cards being designed more for engineers who require detailed calculations. Simulating physical models for construction and animating models for video is not the same thing. But I'm no expert.. :)

Comment: hmm .. I see, Actually I'm doing a search now and reading something out there BUT mainly I'm asking about the BOTTLE-NECKS that are -I am sure- not mentioned anywhere or described.However, an expert or so can describe them here briefly due to his own experience. thanks by the way ;)

Comment: This answer over at SO seems to be pretty authoritative. stackoverflow.com/a/29170393

Comment: You can find Quadro drivers are optimized for stability. I have a quadro and manage several others vs and a few nonquadro workstations. The quadro workstations never crash.  The nonquadro workstations crash every now and then. (we have about 30 quadro workstations and 20 nonquadro ones so not a scientific but anecdotal evidence). For the price im not sure its worth it unless your a pro.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan thanks for the link, it explains the issue somehow detailed enough.  
+joojaa thanks too.

Comment: I've heard the claim about stability before - nice to have confirmation from someone with significant actual experience. (Similarly, if you're a pro you should be using workstations with ECC RAM...)